# Use .find() on a JSON file to get a a string with a specific keyterm

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, parsing

I'm trying to use array.find() to get the first JSON string that contains `amogus`. I've tried to read the JSON file using fs then using JSON.parse() to make it readable. However, I can't seem to get it to do what I want it to do.

JSON file:

`{stuff: ["hosds29083", "amogus1208", "amogus1213"]`

desired output: `amogus1208`

Thanks.

Comment: that is already an object by the looks of it, you simply need to access the property stuff and use array find

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro i know how to use .find() to get strings EQUAL to something, not containing. 
e.g. `{stuff: ["hosds29083", "amogus1208", "amogus1213"]` i can use `array.find(element => element === "amogus1208")`, which then returns the string. however, im trying to have it get the string if it contains the keyword "amogus". i think it would be smth like this: `array.find(element => element.contains('amogus")`, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
const json = JSON.parse(data);
const first = json.stuff.find(obj => obj.includes("your string"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const foundString = yourParsedJsonObject.stuff.find(string => string.includes("amogus"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const json = `{
  "stuff": ["hosds29083", "amogus1208", "amogus1213"]
}`
const data = JSON.parse(json)
const findData = data.stuff.find(s=>s.includes("amogus"))
console.log(findData)
```